# global variable is not updating using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have below global variable and trying to update in diffrent methods

```
var companyName;
```

In this method i am getting company name and can able to print the companyName in terminal

```
var once = async function(myDB) {
    if(once.done) return;

    companyName = await myCacheData.defaultCompany();
    console.log('Company inside once :' + companyName);
};
```

In this method i am trying to get updated company name, which one is updated in side `once()` function. but when i tried to print in terminal it is showing `undefined`.

```
db.dbConnect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        process.exit(1)
    }
    else {
        myDB = db.getDBConnection();
        app.myDB = myDB;
        
        once(myDB);

        console.log('Company inside db call :' + companyName);
    }
});
```

Comment: you need to await the call of `once`.

Comment: `myCacheData.defaultCompany();` may be returning nothing

Comment: Odds are on that `db.getDBConnection()` is also `async` and needs to be awaited as well. But in the context of what you told us , then what @RolandStarke already said

Comment: `async` function don't block.  They return a promise.  If you want to wait for their result to be done, you have to use `.then()` on that promise.

Comment: let me check @RolandStarke answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change this:

```
once(myDB);

console.log('Company inside db call :' + companyName);
```

to :

```
once(myDB).then(v=>console.log('Company inside db call :' + companyName)).catch(v=>console.log('error',v))
```

because `once(myDB)` is `async` and returns a `promise` you can put the callback in the `promise.then(v=>/*your callback*/)`